# Django nonrel and grappelli

Tags: django-nonrel, django-grappelli

I'm trying to install Grappelli on Django-nonrel. Because the current version of Django-nonrel is 1.3 so I use Grappelli 2.3. According to the doc

http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/2.3.9/quickstart.html#setup

I decided to not use staticfiles and edit MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT instead. But I don't know how to config them correctly. I always get 404 error. (localhost)

```
INFO:root:"GET /media/admin/js/grappelli/jquery.grp_autocomplete_generic.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:root:"GET /media/admin/img/admin/default-bg.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:root:"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Current configuration:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = "/static/grappelli/"
MEDIA_URL = "http://localhost:8000/"
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = MEDIA_URL + "grappelli/"
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make the static folders available in app.yaml?

You'd need something in your app.yaml that looks like

```
- url: /grappelli
  static_dir: /static/grappelli
```